# Why is this function approximation correct?

Tags: functions, taylor-expansion, approximation, approximation-theory

I want to show that the following expression:

$$\left |  \frac{  1-\rho }
{1-\rho e^{i\mu -\sigma^2/2}      } \right |^2 $$

Is very well approximated by:

$$\frac{  1 }
{\big (1-\frac{\sigma^2}{2\ln{\rho}} \big)^2+\big (\frac{\mu}{\ln{\rho}} \big)^2     } $$

where $\sigma,\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ smaller than $\pi$ ($\rho$ is smaller but close to 1). Would you have any hint?
I could get to the second form by using $$1-\rho \approx  -\ln{\rho}$$ and $$1-\rho e^{i\mu -\sigma^2/2}\approx -\ln{(\rho e^{i\mu -\sigma^2/2})} \approx -\ln{\rho}-i\mu +\sigma^2/2$$ The second approximation is wrong, but somehow it gives a good result when combined with the first one.